# JavaFX: ¿El método main es obligatorio o no?

Tags: java, javafx

La pregunta es simple. Estuve leyendo algo sobre JavaFX en inglés y decía que el método `main` no es obligatorio, aunque decía después que en algunos casos sí lo era y en otros se podía prescindir de él.

Entonces **¿`main` es prescindible en JavaFX o no?** Si es posible me gustaría ver un ejemplo en el cual se puede prescindir de él.

Comment: El método main es imprescindible por el simple hecho **que es el punto prinicipal de ejecución** de todo programa Java.  Otra cosa distinta es que, en aplicaciones JavaFX **no necesites hacerlo directamente** si usas la [herramienta de empaquetamiento](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/packager.html) de Oracle para generar el JAR.

Answer (score 1):

Consulta los [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/hello_world.htm) de Oracle

> "El main()no se requiere método para aplicaciones JavaFX cuando se crea el archivo JAR para la aplicación con la herramienta de JavaFX empaquetador, que incrusta el JavaFX Launcher en el archivo JAR. Sin embargo, es útil incluir el main()método para que pueda ejecutar archivos JAR que se crearon sin el JavaFX Launcher, como cuando se utiliza un IDE en el que las herramientas JavaFX no están totalmente integrados. Además, las aplicaciones Swing que se incrustan código JavaFX requieren el main()método."

Answer (score 0):

En principio si quieres iniciar el método start necesitarás el launch(args); en el main. Si le quitas el launch el programa se inicia pero no iniciarás la interfaz. Y si no me equivoco launch ha de ir dentro del main por la fuerza.
Otra cosa sería que desde una acción como apretar un botón cambiases de escena. Esa segunda escena no necesitaría de un launch, o lo que es lo mismo: necesitarás el launch en la clase principal.
No soy un experto en javafx pero creo que es así.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno, lo que hace este método es hacer que nuestro ordenador sepa por donde empieza nuestra aplicación.El método main será el punto de partida de nuestro programa, dentro de este método ya se podrán hacer las llamadas a todas las rutinas que compondrán nuestro programa.

Answer (score 0):

El método **main** siempre debe existir debido a que gracias a él se identifica en dónde comienza la aplicación.
Si se tiene un archivo **JAR** en el que no se específico cuál **clase** contiene el **main** nunca se va a iniciar la aplicación.